AWS Cross Account Relations: cloudformation:CreateChangeSet
I am completely new to AWS and have following challenges in relation to cross account deployment and permissions. I have two accounts: master and flower account. My npm script called diff:env states that cdk diff is done from the master account in my flower account. There is a trust relationship between these account so actually everything runs fine. Except for RestApi Stack, where no change set can be created.
[100%] fail: Need to perform AWS calls for account "flower", but the current credentials are for "master"
Could not create a change set, will base the diff on template differences (run again with -v to see the reason).

However I'd like to have a change set for it. Is it possible to fix that, without changing anything in master account and still performing the diff through the master account in the flower account?
